# ¿Puede escindirse el castellano en el futuro?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, historia, dialectos, rae, lingüística

En la evolución de los idiomas a veces uno se escinde en dos o en más. Históricamente vemos el latín que evolucionó hasta los actuales castellano, portugués, italiano...

También observamos que en países que eran uno y se acabaran escindiendo, una lengua común dio paso a distintas denominaciones que, a la larga, pueden acabar siendo idiomas distintos al tener academias de la lengua propias. Me viene a la cabeza el caso de la antigua Yugoslavia con el serbio-croata que ahora a dado paso al serbio, croata, montenegrino y así hasta sumar un idioma por nuevo país.

¿Sería, pues, posible que a la larga el castellano pudiera derivar en distintos idiomas con distintas reglas? Entiendo que actualmente no ocurre por el gran peso que tiene la Real Academia de la Lengua. Pero, ¿qué podría pasar para que esta coexistencia de dialectos bajo un mismo paraguas lingüístico diera lugar a una escisión?

Comment: No entiendo por qué esta pregunta está "on hold". Quizá necesite una discusión en la sección _meta_, pero no creo que esta pregunta sea simplemente "opinion based". A pesar de que es imposible predecir el futuro, todas las respuestas aportan datos más o menos objetivos. La pregunta es "_Puede_ escindirse ..." y no "Se escindirá ...", que creo que es variante suficiente como para poder ser respondida con los datos "a mano" y conocimiento suficiente sin que sea simplemente opinión de cada uno..

Comment: @Diego a mí también me sorprendió. Gracias por tu comentario, he añadido una pregunta en Meta al respecto: [“¿Puede escindirse el castellano en el futuro?” on hold?](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2437/1674).

Comment: @Diego **[Relevant meta discussion.](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2437/puede-escindirse-el-castellano-en-el-futuro-on-hold/2439#2439)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

¿Puede?  Absolutamente.  De hecho ya ha pasado hasta cierto punto (desde el castellano áurico tenemos el ladino, y más recientemente tenemos los criollos como chavacano o pelenquero).

Pero que pase de nuevo en el futuro, lo dudo sinceramente.  La oportunidad ya nos ha pasado por dos razones: aumento en intercomunicación y mejoras en sistemas educativos.

¿Hay diferencias dialectales hoy en día?  Sí.  Pero las diferencias suelen dimuinuirse con la intercomunicación.  Y si salen diferencias, con un estándar para comunicación internacional, es menos probable que estas diferencias engendren otras diferencias más ajenas al estándar.

Y aunque históricamente algunos países, por razones de guerra, dinero, etcétera, no han tenido los mejores sistemas educativos, todo va mejorándose y creo que ahora todos los países hispanohablantes tienen sistemas educativos universales (aunque quizás no en práctica). Las diferencias dialectales suelen estar más marcadas en el habla de los con menos formación educativa.  No lo digo en absoluto como algo malo, pero es evidente cuánto más alto el nivel educativo se tiene, cuánto más culto se habla.  Y el habla (o escritura) culta casi se define por carecer de rasgos dialectales; el español estándar simplemente no es algo que alguien hable nativamente.

Ya que hay cada día más intercomunicación y mejores sistemas educativos, la posibilidad de que un país o región hispanohablante vaya diferenciando su lengua tanto que llegue a ser otra me parece bastante improbable.  La lengua evolucionará, pero con todos los países juntos.  Pero bueno, siempre es posible que en algún momento futuro, no sé, que la comunidad de Murcia se ponga de Corea de Norte y bloquee toda la comunicación extranjera y en cien años cuando podamos comunicarnos con ellos, haya una diferencia suficiente grande que lo que se hablare allí (que bueno, lo que hablan allí ya es bastante raro jajajaja) lo podremos denominar otro idioma.

Comment: Fantástica respuesta, guifa. Entiendo pues que en un contexto como el actual es muy complicado que tal escisión ocurra. Sobre Murcia, me reí mucho con esta noticia falsa [El Ejército acude a Murcia para ver si aún vive gente allí](http://www.elmundotoday.com/2010/11/el-ejercito-acude-a-murcia-para-ver-si-aun-vive-gente-alli/)

Comment: Tu mención de los medios de comunicación masivos va directo al meollo del asunto. Fíjate en la enorme homogeneización de la lengua inglesa en los E.E.U.U, desde que se hizo posible la transmisión simultánea de programas de televisión y radio a todo el país en los años  60. En los años que viví en el país en la década de los 90, encontraba personas en los lugares más insospechados que hablaban con el acento y el dialecto del centro de California pero no eran de allí Y acá en América todos tenemos gran influencia dialectal mejicana debido a que la mayoría de los doblajes se hacen allá.

Answer (score 3):

El lenguaje es absolutamente social. Tienes razón al mencionar que la Real Academia Española tiene un gran peso, el determinar qué es lo que llegase a pasar para que de esta lengua surja una nueva, o nuevos dialectos escindiéndose la lengua por completo, es a mi punto de vista, algo subjetivo y que merece un estudio profundo y prolongado planteándose varias posturas. Por lo menos esta sería la mía.

Respondiendo a la pregunta "qué podría pasar", consideraría que ver las referencias históricas sería un buen punto de comienzo.

Vemos que el Latín es una lengua que se masificó considerablemente, para que pudieran surgir nuevas lenguas fue necesario que el idioma conquistador (el latín) se impusiera por el conquistado y se mezclaran sus lenguas. En ningún lugar donde llegó el latín se mantuvo el idioma íntegramente, dado que fue el latín vulgar el que se esparció y quienes lo llevaban a cuestas eran soldados, no había un preocupación de proporcionar una "educación" sobre el nuevo idioma que los pueblos conquistados debían adoptar. Esta era una forma poderosa de dominio por sobre el otro y una forma poderosa e influyente de crear nuevas lenguas.

Volviendo a la actualidad, si bien las conquistas no son como antaños, podemos ver que sí se mantiene un rasgo muy importante; la mezcla de lenguas. Vemos en Miami que muchos latinos residentes, personas que aprenden el inglés y que hablan el español, para formar una oración utilizan ambos idiomas, cumpliendo favorablemente, en su contexto, con la comprensión y comunicación; factores principales del lenguaje.

El punto que quiero abordar es que frente a un contexto, una fenómeno social de mezclas de lenguas sí podría provocar nuevos dialectos con nuevas reglas, donde tendría que verse el progreso a través de los años y ser aceptados socialmente como formas y reglas que cumplan con la comunicación. También debemos considerar que para que esto suceda, un grupo considerable de personas vayan transformando el español y siendo aceptados como una nueva lengua.

A mi punto de vista, el español puede escindirse en la manera que cierto grupo de personas considere que el transformarlo y construir nuevas reglas vaya a cumplir con el objetivo de comunicarse de una forma más eficaz, que se acomode a estos "nuevos hablantes" y se formalicen estas nuevas reglas como un nuevo idioma.

Antes que pase a ser escrito, debe ser hablado (a mi opinión) y aceptado socialmente para considerar y forjar una evolución del idioma o crear uno nuevo.